# Double integral of exponential function with absolute value

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Consider the following integral:

$\int_{-\infty}^{y}\int_{-\infty}^{x} exp(-|x'-y'|) \,dx'dy'$

Assume without loss of generality that $x \geq y$, we have:

$\int_{-\infty}^{y}\int_{-\infty}^{x} exp(-|x'-y'|) \,dx'dy'=\int_{-\infty}^{y}\int_{-\infty}^{y'} exp(-|x'-y'|) \,dx'dy'+\int_{-\infty}^{y}\int_{y'}^{x} exp(-|x'-y'|) \,dx'dy'$
$=\int_{-\infty}^{y}\int_{-\infty}^{y'} exp(-(y'-x')) \,dx'dy'+\int_{-\infty}^{y}\int_{y'}^{x} exp(-(x'-y')) \,dx'dy'$
$=\int_{-\infty}^{y}1dy'+\int_{-\infty}^{y}-exp(-(x-y'))+1 dy'$
$=\int_{-\infty}^{y}2dy'+\int_{-\infty}^{y}-exp(-(x-y'))dy'$

The integral of a constant at the end here appears to blow up. Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behaviour? Intuitively it feels like $exp(-|x-y|)$ should be integrable over $\mathbb{R^2}$?

Comment: It is expected a little bit. Notice that on the line $y=x$, the function is $1$, it never decays. Consider the rotated and scaled version $f(x,y) = \exp(-|x|)$. Does this one converge?

Comment: Good point, I suspected it might have something to do with the y=x line but the rotated version makes it much more clear.